# Print a given number pattern from user input using nested for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I am new to programming. Am currently learning Java, on nested loop now, and got stuck.

So what I want to do is to write a program that takes an integer from user and

print lines, for example if user input was 4 then the result should be like:

```
1

1 2

1 2 3

1 2 3 4
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of rows:");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it prints one extra line at the end, like:

```
1

1 2

1 2 3

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4
```

And it is hard for me to figure out why.

I guess it is my first for loop but I don't know how to fix the for loop to get the result I want.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean, one extra line at the end

Comment: @Stultuske just added in the post, thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: Remove `System.out.println(i);` and add `System.out.println();` after the nested for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't print anything from the outer loop, only new line

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the trailing spaces of the other answers,
rather than printing `i` at the start of the loop, print `1`.
Then start the inner loop from `2` and print a space *before* each value. And print a new line after the inner loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    System.out.print("1");
    for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" " + j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Prints:

> 1 
>   1 2 
>   1 2 3 
>   1 2 3 4

Answer (score 0):

The problem is printing a newline and `i` at the same time... just take care of the new line after your `for` loop. The inner loop can handle all the prints.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of rows:");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Let's us dry run it
at first you print 
1
then newline
then j goes from 1 to 1 nut no newline now 2 is printed by i now newline
so result 1 2
again j goes like 1 , 2 but no newline so again 3 is printed by i then newline
so result 1 2 3 
again j goes like 1 , 2, 3, but no newline so again 4 is printed by i then newline
so result 1 2 3 4
again j goes like 1 , 2, 3, 4 // this one is the extra line
```